# File URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an action in my controller:

```
def download
    @file = FilmFile.find(params[:film_file_id])
    @file.film.downloads += 1
    @file.film.save
    send_file @file.real_name.path, content_type: @file.real_name.content_type, x_sendfile: true
end
```

but in Chrome downloads I see URLs to files like `http://site.org/film_files/1004/download`

Is there a way to make URLs like this `http://site.org/path/to/file/file.mp4` instead of `http://site.org/film_files/1004/download`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the example in the [CarrierWave wiki](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to%3a-secure-upload).

You need to add a new route:

**routes.rb**

```
match "/film_files/:id/:basename.:extension", :controller => "films", :action => "download", :conditions => { :method => :get }
```

And then assuming that the filename of your file is `:basename.:extension` you just need to generate the route in your views using the **id** of the film_file and the **filename** of the document

eg:

```
= link_to "Download !", "/film_files/#{@film.id}/#{File.basename(@film.document.url)}"
```

So that the generated url would have both the filename and the extension !